# Find Modulus, Real and imaginary part of $\frac{(1+i)(1+i)^2(1+i)^3...(1+i)^{20}}{i^0+i^2+i^4+i^6+...+i^{20}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

How to solve this task (find modulus, real and imaginary part)?
$$z = \frac{(1+i)(1+i)^2(1+i)^3...(1+i)^{20}}{i^0+i^2+i^4+i^6+...+i^{20}}$$

Comment: Hint: $i^0 + i^2 + \cdots + i^{20} = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{10} (-1)^k$ and, for any complex number $w$, one can write as $w = \vert w\vert (\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$

Comment: Using computer algebra:  the term is $40564819207303340847894502572032 i$.

Comment: Well as $i^{4k + n} = i^n$ and $i^0=1, i^1 =i, i^2 =-1; i^3 = -i$ the denominator is easy.  And the numerator is $(1+i)^{1+2+3+.... + 20}$ which is easy if you know polar notation.  And if you don't, binomial theory makes it .... not impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much! At first I did a mistake in the transformation so I did not obtain anything adequate, but then I redone it and everything is solved!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=x+iy=1+i$, then $r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and $\cos(\theta) =x/r =1/\sqrt{2}$, $\sin(\theta)=r/y=1/\sqrt{2}$, this implies that $\theta =\pi/4$, and there fore we have $w=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$.  Then we have

$$|z| =|\frac{{(\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4})}^{\sum_{i=1}^{20}i}}{6(1) + 5(-1)}|=\sqrt{2}^{\frac{20(20+1)}{2}}  |e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{20(20+1)}{2} }|=2^{105}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very useful! Then I did it without the exponent in order to find a Real and Imaginary part and if I am correct they are equal to: $$Im(z)=sin(\frac{105\pi}{2})$$ $$Re(z)=cos(\frac{105\pi}{2})$$